# Doctrine get some columns and associated entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to do a very simple thing here but seems I can't get DQL quite yet. Furthermore, google decides to make my day hard by returning results for "SQL" when I type in "DQL" in it.

I have an Article entity with various properties. One of them is associated Image entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Image", inversedBy="articles")
 */
protected $image;
```

Now, to prevent Lazy loading and unnecessary load that it generates, I want to do this get **Article.title and Article.image**, nothing more! Just name of article and it's associated image (whole image entity).

How do I do that? I tried everything I came up with in hope that something will actually work and that I would be able to examine why that works and other things not, but I just can't get it to work.

Here is most sane version of query I came up with, only if it would work:

```
public function getTitleBackground($id)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
               ->select('a.title, a.id', 'i')
               ->leftJoin('a.image', 'i')
               ->where('a.id = :id')
               ->setParameter('id', $id);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

This returns me this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("[Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT a.title,': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.") in PIFlexBlogBundle:Admin/Page:commentEdit.html.twig at line 13

This "fixes" up when I add `a` in my `->select()` but then it selects all article fields for me, which is just what I'm trying to evade.

*Note: I'm using this inside symfony2 repository class.*

Comment: Could you show the details of Article and Image entity with related properties on the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the DQL partial object syntax : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#partial-object-syntax

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I managed to do it by reading reference you gave me. Would have never found it myself. Its hard to find things on google when you don't know what you're searching for :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to AdrienBrault's answer, I managed to make a query.

```
public function getTitleBackground()
{
    // Pure DQL
    $q = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT partial a.{id,title} FROM PIFlexBlogBundle:Article a JOIN a.image i');

    // OOP building DQL through queryBuilder
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
               ->select('partial a.{id, title}')
               ->join('a.image', 'i');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Both raw DQL and DQL made through query builder give the same result.

Note, this returns all Articles, to get by **id** just add WHERE clause to them.